# How to use CAtlComModule to implement a COM event sink?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I try to refactor an existing and **working** COM event sink implementation. The event sink class is written in C++ and resides in a DLL that uses the deprecated [`CComModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1300df24.aspx) class. The goal of the refactoring is to replace `CComModule` by the new ATL 7.0 class [CAtlComModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h4fdwzf.aspx).

The existing implementation declares a global variable somewhere in a .cpp file:

```
CComModule _Module;
```

As you can see the variable has the usual "magic" name `_Module`. The customary initialization is missing, though, nowhere is there a call to `CComModule::Init()` and there is also no COM object map in the DLL project. The event sink still works, its event handler methods get properly called.

Lacking any documentation how to transition from `CComModule` to `CAtlComModule`, I naively attempted to change the variable declaration to this:

```
CAtlComModule _Module;
```

It didn't work out, though: After the change the event sink stopped working, i.e. its event handler methods no longer get called.

Does anyone know the steps one is supposed to perform to migrate to `CAtlComModule`? So far I have been unable to dig up a solution either on MSDN or via Google, but maybe I did not look properly...

BTW: If necessary I can provide more details about the event sink implementation, but so far I felt that the problem is not in this area.

Comment: I'd say look heavy at CAtlDllModuleT<T> if this were a class-not-registered flame-out, but your's is just an event sink, which shouldn't even really need registration if in-proc in the traditional sense, so I'm (temporarily at least) stymied as well.

Comment: Why are you doing this in first place? You can always create an empty new ATL project and see how modules are defined there.

Comment: @RomanR. In the meantime I tried exactly that, but I am not overly pleased with the result. The empty new ATL project does stuff that I don't really want to drag over into my project. It creates a DllMain(), uses a new class that derives from CAtlDllModuleT, dynamically links to ATL but not to MFC. This is all stuff that was not necessary for using CComModule. I will have a closer look at those changes if no one has a simpler solution.

Comment: Well if you want to upgrade your existing project, this is exactly what you need to try to follow. `CComModule` as you found already is just a deprecated stub to stay compatible/buildable and nothing more.

Comment: @RomanR. OK, I will take the new ATL project as a guideline for further research, but something in me refuses to just take the stuff that it suggests at face value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest "new style" replacement for `CComModule` looks like this:

```
class MyModule : public CAtlDllModuleT<MyModule> {};
MyModule _Module;
```